# call a Lua function just by writing its name (without parentheses)

Tags: function, variables, lua

I'm looking forward to using a variable like "asdf" instead of writing the name function to check its return (which changes now and then). That's why "asdf" variable should update its value everytime we use (call) it

Is there any way to do this in Lua, please?

```
asdf == getFunction() --we define it here

     (...)            --some code 

if asdf < 10 then ... --here we call the variable (so it should get/update again the result of getFunction())
```

thanks

Comment: Do you hate parenthesis so much?

Comment: Lisp has a feature like this (symbol macros)

Comment: @user2308704 From what you've indicated in your comments so far, it seems like you're trying to solve the wrong problem. Maybe you should rethink whatever you're trying to do? As the answer demonstrates, doing something like this isn't _impossible_ per se, but it's certainly unusual and should be unnecessary under most circumstances.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
--we define it here
local asdf = function ()  
  return getFunction()
end

--some code 
(...)            

--here we call the variable 
--(so it should get/update again the result of getFunction())
if asdf() < 10 then ...
```

---

**UPD :**
Solution without parenthesis

```
--we define it here
asdf = nil
setmetatable(_G, {__index =
   function(t, k)
      if k == 'asdf' then
         return getFunction()
      end
   end
})

--some code
(...)

--here we call the variable
--(so it should get/update again the result of getFunction())
if asdf < 10 then ...
```

Comment: yea, but the problem here is that I would have to use those parenthesis "asdf()", isn't any other way? =(

Comment: @user2308704 - Do you have a problem with parenthesis on your keyboard?

Comment: @user2308704 - Or maybe you are making some Lua-based DSL?

Comment: nono, is just that I need them to be without parenthesis. Trying to make a reader for some scripts, and these scripts have variables such as those without the "()". Thanks a lot Egooor!!!!

Comment: @user2308704: Well, those scripts aren't *Lua* then.

Comment: @NicolBolas - I didn't understand your phrase `the only thing`.  Why `the only`?

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff: No, you're right. I forgot that it checks the table to see if it already exists and always returns that if it does.

Comment: Yay! A (good!) answer from @EgorSkriptunoff provided as an answer, not as a comment! ;)

Comment: isn't `_ENV` preferable to `_G` in newer versions of lua?

Comment: @Julian - `_G` is more compatible